# Graphite - aggregation / retention

Tags: graphite

I am a bit newbie in Graphite so would be grateful if you help me / give some hints for configuration files.
What I need:

- Having multiple servers and being able to send metrics from these servers. Metrics should be summarised ( aggregationMethod: sum ). So if I have registration metric and there were 3 registration per 5 min on one server and 2 registration per 5 min on second one, I should see 5 registration per 5 min in Graphite. Please correct me if I am wrong, but it should be possible with ( in storage-aggregation.conf ):

> ```
> [all]
> pattern = .*
> xFilesFactor = 0
> aggregationMethod = sum
> ```

- I also need to have one metric with 1s:3y resolution and being able to aggregate it during 3 hours. What do I mean by that is I should report the following:

> ```
> Name: custom_metric Time: 00000 Value: 1 ( Reported now )
> Name: custom_metric Time: 00001 Value: 1 ( Reported 1 second from now )
> ..............
> Name: custom_metric Time: 00000 Value: 1 ( Reported 2h 59m from now )
> ```

Eventually, I should see a value of 2 for a custom_metric at time 0000.

As far as I understand, StatsD is not suitable for me because it accepts only real-time metrics.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the carbon-aggregator service.

Look in your /opt/graphite/conf/aggregation-rules.conf.example for an example configuration file and documentation here: [Graphite carbon-aggregation.conf documentation](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#aggregation-rules-conf)

I use statsd instead of this. carbon-relay-ng does aggregation as well.